# Why doesn't this integral return a symbolic result, but when evaluted in Plot returns the correct function?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I have the intgeral 
$$f(z_{0}) = \int_{z_{0}}^{\infty} |z| \exp(- a z^{2}) \, \mathrm{d}z$$

Which I compute with

```
Integrate[Abs[z] Exp[- a z^2], {z, z0, Infinity}]
```

which returns

```
\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(z0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(\(-a\)\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(z\), \(2\)]\)]\ Abs[z]\) \[DifferentialD]z\)\)
```

which is simply the symbolic form of my input. However if I now turn my integral into a function with `Èvaluate` with

```
IntegralFunction[a_, z0_] := Evaluate[Integrate[Abs[z] Exp[- a z^2], {z, z0, Infinity}]]
```

And then plot with some values

```
Plot[IntegralFunction[1, z0], {z0, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

You can see we can a result.

Why does this integral not return a symbolic result? Is this integral simply ill defined?
Why does `Plot` return something, is it basically calling `NIntegrate` to do the plot?

Comment: That explains that bit! I guess Mathematica can't solve the `Abs[z]` bit, I suppose the solution is to use piecewise?

Comment: Plot works because IntegralFunction returns numbers, which can be plotted. For example, IntegralFunction[1, -1] is a number. Indeed, Integrate[Abs[z] Exp[-a z^2], {z, -1, Infinity}] returns a conditional expression based on the sign of the real part of a.

Comment: `NIntegrate` it is then!

Comment: For real `z`, `Abs[z] == Sqrt[z^2]` then 

`Integrate[Sqrt[z^2] Exp[-a z^2], {z, z0, Infinity}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because when you give numbers for the parameters, `Integrate` need not assume they are complex numbers of unknown value. You can use assumptions to tell it enough to do the integral symbolically:

```
Assuming[ a > 0 && Element[z0, Reals], 
   Integrate[Abs[z] Exp[-a z^2], {z, z0, Infinity}]]
```

yields

```
Piecewise[{{1/(E^(a*z0^2)*(2*a)), z0 >= 0}},
           (-1 + 2*E^(a*z0^2))/(E^(a*z0^2)*(2*a))]
```

Comment: Give that man a coconut!